# Split List into Equal Chunks and Append Last sublist to Previous sublists

Tags: python, list

I'm dividing a List into Small Parts Based on a number provided by the user in a JSON file. A lot of times last sublist of divided list has less elements that DivideLen. That's why I want to append these elements evenly to previous sublists and delete last sublist. But for some reason Last sublist ends up having 1 element. How can I fix it?

```
# Length of OList is 29
DivideLen = 12
OList = [
    "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
    "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
    "K", "L", "M", "N", "O",
    "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T",
    "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y",
    "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC",
]

# Divide OList to multiple small list of length 12
DividedList = [OList[i:i + DivideLen] for i in range(0, len(OList), DivideLen)]

"""
[
  [
    "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
    "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
    "K", "L"
  ],
  [
    "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q",
    "R", "S", "T", "U", "V",
    "W", "X"
  ],
  [
    "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC"
  ]
]
"""

LastIndex = len(DividedList) - 1
LastList = DividedList[LastIndex]

if len(DividedList) > 1 and len(LastList) < DivideLen:
    # Run a Loop from Zero to Less then the Index of Last List of DividedList
    for i in range(0, LastIndex):
        for elem in LastList:
            print(f"Length of List {i} Before: {len(DividedList[i])}")
            print(f"Length of Last List Before: {len(DividedList[LastIndex])}")
            DividedList[i].append(elem)
            DividedList[LastIndex].remove(elem)
            print(f"Length of List {i} After: {len(DividedList[i])}")
            print(f"Length of Last List After: {len(DividedList[LastIndex])}")

"""
Length of List 0 Before: 12
Length of Last List Before: 5
Length of List 0 After: 13
Length of Last List After: 4
Length of List 0 Before: 13
Length of Last List Before: 4
Length of List 0 After: 14
Length of Last List After: 3
Length of List 0 Before: 14
Length of Last List Before: 3
Length of List 0 After: 15
Length of Last List After: 2
Length of List 1 Before: 12
Length of Last List Before: 2
Length of List 1 After: 13
Length of Last List After: 1

"""
```

**Current Result**

```
DividedList =[
  [
    "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
    "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
    "K", "L", "Y", "Z", "AA",
  ],
  [
    "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q",
    "R", "S", "T", "U", "V",
    "W", "X", "AB"
  ]
  [
     "AC"
  ]
]
```

**Expected Result**

```
"""
DividedList =[
  [
    "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
    "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
    "K", "L", "Y", "Z", "AA",
  ],
  [
    "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q",
    "R", "S", "T", "U", "V",
    "W", "X", "AB", "AC"
  ]
]
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if len(DividedList) > 1:
    # If length of Final Sub List in Less than the Quiz Question Limit
    LastIndex = len(DividedList) - 1
    LastList = DividedList[LastIndex]
    if len(LastList) < DivideLen:
        i = 0
        while(len(LastList) > 0):
            if i >= LastIndex:
                i = 0
            DividedList[i].append(LastList[0])
            LastList.remove(LastList[0])
            i = i + 1
```